# Swift - Get one-to-many relationship

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, one-to-many, fetchrequest

let's imagine that we have 2 entities:

-People (name, age, ..)

-House (color)

we recorded the data several times with `house.addToPeople (newPeople)` for each house

we want to get all the people of the house colored blue

how do we fetch this?

I tried this code but it gets all the people

```
        let appD = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
            let context = appD.persistentContainer.viewContext
        
        
        let peopleFetch = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: "People")

        let houseFetch = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: "House")               
        houseFetch.fetchLimit = 1       
        houseFetch.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "color = %@", "blue")
    
        ...
        
        let res = try? context.fetch(peopleFetch)
        let resultData = res as! [People]
```

how to do this ?

Comment: Execute the fetch for the house instead (houseFetch), the other one is irrelevant, and then access the people form your house object using the `people` attribute

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this function. What it does is fetching all of the People and creating an array with all of the results.

```swift
func getAllItems() -> [People]? {
        let request = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: "People")
        request.returnsObjectsAsFaults = false
        
        do {
            let result: NSArray = try context.fetch(request) as NSArray
            return (result as? [People])!
        } catch let error {
            print("Errore recupero informazioni dal context \n \(error)")
        }
        return nil
    }
```

If you want to perform your search following certain criteria such as a color, use the following code after `request`:

```swift
//Here i'm searching by index, if you need guidance for your case don't hesitate asking
 request.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "index = %d", currentItem.index)
```

Edit: actually the code above is just to get all of the people, if you want to base your search on the houses do the following:

```swift
  func retrieve()-> [People]{
//Fetch all of the houses with a certain name
        let houseRequest = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: "House")
        houseRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "name = %@", "newName") //This seearch is by name
        houseRequest.returnsObjectsAsFaults = false
        do {
//put the fetched items in an array
            let result: NSArray = try context.fetch(houseRequest) as NSArray
            let houses = result as? [Houses]
//Get the people from the previous array
            let people: [People]? = (houses.people!.allObjects as! [People])
            return people
        } catch let error {
            print("Errore recupero informazioni dal context \n \((error))")
        }
            return nil
        
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your answer !

In this example "houses" is an array, so we have to add an index ➔ `houses[0].people!.AllObjects`

And thank you very much for your explanation.